# Scale an HTML table to fit onto a PDF page in TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

Is it possible to render a HTML table into PDF using TCPDF and scale it to fit the page? I have many columns in my table. Would it be possible to zoom out or scale it down so it fits?

[image: coloured table cut off by edge of PDF page]

Answer (score 2):

TCPDF allows you to write HTML. This way, your table structure does not matter.

Example:

```
$tbl = <<<EOD
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th rowspan="3">Left column</th>
<th colspan="5">Heading Column Span 5</th>
<th colspan="9">Heading Column Span 9</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th rowspan="2">Rowspan 2<br />This is some text that fills the table cell.</th>
<th colspan="2">span 2</th>
<th colspan="2">span 2</th>
<th rowspan="2">2 rows</th>
<th colspan="8">Colspan 8</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>1a</th>
<th>2a</th>
<th>1b</th>
<th>2b</th>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
<th>4</th>
<th>5</th>
<th>6</th>
<th>7</th>
<th>8</th>
</tr>
</table>
EOD;

$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
```

[See Full Full Code](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_048.phps) | [See PDF Output](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_048.pdf)

Comment: i mean  .. table just overflows way to its right .. it there such a way to make it fit in the page ? like some kind a auto-fit into the page..

Answer (score 1):

Send the page dimensions to avoid that.
Set your array variable with width and height like this.

```
$pageDimension = array('500,300'); //width,height
```

Substitute this array value where you use this pre-defined TCPDF variable (`PDF_PAGE_FORMAT`)

Replace `PDF_PAGE_FORMAT` with `$pageDimension`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to not give your table a custom column width to have the results you want but there will be a lot of wrapping depending on on your content. i think the better way is to choose a different page type like A3 instead of A4 and landscape it.